# cg-125, missing problem in speed bike loose power and then regain after 1 2 seconds

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor

Whenever i increase the speed at 1st gear the bike at high speed looses the power. On start of second gear bike start to do missing. Then at high speed problem sometime occur sometime ir doesnot.
I have check current problem CDI, coil, magnet karra, but it doesnot solve problem. But when i remove pipe between the filter and the carburetor bike become clear and did no missing. I dont know how filter create problem in misisn or the black pipe between them. Is this due to air not going well into carburetor?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the cg 125 have an accelerator pump, its function is to enrich the mixture when rapidly opening throttle, to avoid this symptom. It could be linked to your problem if it is not working correctly.

Comment: So what should i do now?